# Find all continuous positive functions $h$ on [0,1] st $ \int_0^1 h(t) dt=1, \int_0^1h(x)\sin(\pi t)dt=c,\int_0^1h(t)\sin^2(\pi t)dt=c^2$with $c\in R$

Tags: calculus

Problem: Find all continuous functions $h:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+$ so that $$\int_0^1 h(t) dt = 1,\; \int_0^1 h(x)\sin(\pi t)dt = c,\;\int_0^1 h(t)\sin^2(\pi t)dt = c^2$$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$

The solution is in the answer.

Comment: Why do you suddenly use $f(x)$ rather than $h(x)$ at the beginning of the question?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^1h(t)(\sin \pi t-c)^2=0$ therefore $h(t)(\sin \pi t-c)^2=0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. There is at most two $t_0$ and $t_1$ such that $(\sin \pi t-c)^2=0$ and $h$ is zero outside of $\{t_0,t_1\}$ Since $h$ is continuous, $h\equiv 0$ the integral cannot be one: $h$ does not exist.